# AngularFire - How to define item ID for child template with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularfire

Maybe my issue seems easy to resolve, but I've this problem since a lot of hours : When I'm in my dashboard, all data of my Firebase database are visible (With Ng-repeat).
But I can't found a solution for choose one specific item and see his details in another page.

I've test this method in HTML (This is an example) :

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">

<div class="card" ng-href="#/post/">">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.content}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

In App JS :

```
  .state('tabpost', {
  url: 'tabpost/id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
  })
```

In Service JS (in Post Factory) :

```
 myApp.factory("Post", ["$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject", function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
var postRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts/');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Users/');
var posts = $firebaseArray(postRef);

     var Post = {

         all: posts,

         get: function (postKey){
          var postId = $firebaseObject(postRef);
                return $firebaseObject(eventRef.child('Posts').child(postId).child(userid));

              }
            ,
        add: function (post){
          var postId = $firebaseArray(postRef, userRef);
          event.userid = userRef.getAuth();
                return postId.$add(post);
              }
       }
       return Post;

}]);
```

My PostCtrl :

```
myApp.controller('PostCtrl', ['$ionicFrostedDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate','$state','$scope', 'Post', 'Auth', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function($ionicFrostedDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $state,$scope, Post, Auth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

  var PostRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts");

  $scope.posts = Post.all;

  $scope.post = {'title': '', 'content': ''};

  $scope.auth = Auth;
```

PS : It took 16 hours to try a bunch of tutorials mostly obsolete , and I am sure that the solution can not be that simple.

I already posted two similar issues yesterday and this morning but each of the proposed solutions have not worked . I would be immensely grateful to the person who would help me out of this impasse .

I still have a little trouble with jsFiddle promised I would learn to use it once I would have solved this problem.

Thank you for giving me time

Comment: should it be ` url: 'tabpost/:id'`?

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: It's corrected, but I've the same result : Don't work ...

Comment: The worst in this story it's I have not error, I've probably forget one thing, but what ?

Comment: Should you be calling `Post.get(id)` instead of `Post.all`. Let me put this in an answer, then you can try

Comment: Thank you, I'll be waiting :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following set of codes, I've explained the changes in comments in Controller and added `:id` in App JS

In App JS :

```
  .state('tabpost', {
  url: 'tabpost/:id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
  })
```

PostCtrl :

```
myApp.controller('PostCtrl', ['$ionicFrostedDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate','$state','$scope', 'Post', 'Auth', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$routeParams', function($ionicFrostedDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $state,$scope, Post, Auth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams) {

  var PostRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts");

  var id = $routeParams.id; //get the id from url, $routeParams is injected in controller

  $scope.posts = Post.get(id); //call get() method of Post with the id retrieved

  $scope.post = {'title': '', 'content': ''};

  $scope.auth = Auth;
```

Comment: I've a error message : Error: Could not resolve 'postId : post.id' from state 'tabdash', thanks for your time

Comment: hmmm.. Guess more of service code is needed then. Can you post that?

Comment: cool.. what's `postId` and `userid`? which one of these is the `id` that you pass in URL param?

Comment: The user who created post as logged with Facebook, I want to display his name and his picture, it is for that we have "userid".
For postid, this is the content of post previously write by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use route provider to do that. I used that for my application and it works great.

```
myApp.config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('tabpost', {
            templateUrl: 'tabpost/id', 
            controller: 'PostCtrl' 
        });
}]);
```

Comment: @YngDev31 this should be in appjs

Comment: Ok, the page who all posts are display is named tabdash , and single post page is tabpost . With this this is always correct or I must make change in your snippets ? thanks @Coding Enthusiast